# Pstreams - how to write to stdin and get the output?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm looking for a working example of how to use pstreams. I'm planning to open an ssh session with a remote host, execute a command and receive its output. So far I got this:

```
#include <pstreams/pstream.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    redi::pstream proc("ssh localhost -t -t", redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstdin);
    std::string line;
    std::cout.flush();
    while (std::getline(proc.out(), line)){
        std::cout << "stdout: " << line << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it's not working as expected. Instead of seeing:

```
stdout: archer@localhost:
```

I get this:

```
archer@localhost:
```

**@Update**
Few minutes ago I've noticed that after entering the password I get the right output. It seems that the openssh is somehow blocking my program from sending the text to stdout.
Here's an example:

```
#include <pstreams/pstream.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "1\n";
    redi::pstream proc("ssh localhost -t -t", redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstdin);
    std::cout << "2\n";
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "3\n";
    std::cout.flush();
    std::cout << "4\n";
    while (std::getline(proc.out(), line)){
        std::cout << "5\n";
        std::cout << " " << "stdout: " << line << '\n';
        std::cout << "6\n";
    }
    std::cout << "7\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
archer@localhost's password:
```

Here I have to enter the password and the rest looks like this:

```
5
 stdout: Last login: Wed Nov 12 14:57:36 2014 from localhost.localdomain
6
5
 stdout:
```

My first guess is that "archer@localhost's password:" outputted by the SSH is not stored in the pstreams object buffer (proc.out()).

Comment: `\`n\`` should be `\`\n\`` or `std::endl`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Well that's one thing, but it doesn't solve the main problem.

Comment: Try to use `line.c_str()` instead and call `std::cout.flush()` after your output.

Comment: @Pickle It didn't solve the problem. The output is still the same.

Comment: Strange. Surround your while with `{`and `}`, perhaps something is messing with the `operator<<` synchronization.

Comment: @Pickle Still nothing. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: `std::cout.flush()` before the `while` loop. EDIT: you could try `proc.flush()` too.

Comment: @Pickle After putting the std::flush() before the while loop, nothing's changed. I still have to enter the password to see the output. When I tried to use proc.flush() (just after cout.flush()) it got even worse. I didn't see anything even after entering the password.

Comment: I see the problem. The `pstream::flush()` function somehow messes with the standard output (it is also called once implicitly in your program). I'll have to verify the source codes to confirm how exactly. The temporary fix is to append something to the beginning of your `cout` stream, eg. `cout << " " << ...`. It's dirty but it can fix the problem (temporarily)

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the edit. What do you expect after the second `5
 stdout: `?

Comment: @Pickle I expect that instead of "archer@localhost's password:" I will get "stdout: archer@localhost's password:" and I will be able to send the password instead of entering it manually.

Comment: What I don't understand is who outputs "`archer@localhost's password:`" before you have to enter the pwd? At what stage is this printed?

Comment: @Pickle I guess that it is printed by the ssh program. It's output is not stored in a pstream buffer like it's supposed to. Instead it is simply thrown to the console.

Comment: @Pickle Look, it's pretty simple. I'm calling an SSH program. It SHOULD be ran as child process and its output SHOULD be redirected to the pstream object (or something similar). When the SSH successfully connects to the localhost it asks about the password. The "archer@localhost's password:" shouldn't be thrown to the console as it currently is. Instead it should be stored in the buffer (proc.out()). Unfortunately it is not happening and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. I've managed to solve my problem. Here's the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/569432/why-can-i-see-password-prompts-through-redirecting-output. The workaround is to use telnet. Here's an example of a working code:

```
#include <pstreams/pstream.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string buffer;
    redi::pstream proc("telnet localhost", redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstdin | redi::pstreams::pstderr);
    while (proc >> buffer){
        std::cout << buffer << '\n';
        if (buffer.find("gin") != std::string::npos) // login
            break;
    }
    proc << "my_login" << std::endl;
    while (proc >> buffer){
        std::cout << buffer << '\n';
        if (buffer.find("sword") != std::string::npos) //password
            break;
    }
    proc << "my_pass" << std::endl;
    sleep(1);
    proc << "ls" << std::endl;
    while (proc >> buffer){
        std::cout << buffer << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```